# What are the swords in LOTR made of

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, weapon

What are swords/knives such as Sting, Anduril, Guthwine made of? Iron? Steel? Mithril?

Comment: Metal, I'd wager.

Comment: Just those three? In general?

Comment: Re: Sting, in the film at least, Gandalf says they are made of Elves......................."the blade is of Elvish make" ;D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I was just giving examples

Comment: Any idea why think any known sword would be made of a metal other then steel?

Comment: @Mithoron Iron if steel wasn't common yet (though they do mention steel in LOTR) or mithril for added strength

Comment: I do not think any named swords were made of mithril, in part because of the expense and in part because of their age. Narsil/Anduril, for example, was made in the First Age by a dwarf of Nogrod, whereas mithril came exclusively from Moria. Similarly, String was made in Gondolin. But I think mithril may not have been suitable for weaponry; I can't think of anything but armor, helms, gates, and inscriptions said to be made of mithril.

Answer (score 0):

Steel or Mithril mostly with a sprinkle of magic.

I don't believe there is any reference in the books or to the material that was used. Only just general nods that the Elves were smithing with steel and/or Mithril in the first age when those, at least Sting, was created. Granted they were doing something in their smithing process that seemed magical to other races. Hence, why Sting glows blue.

Comment: Not so clear there's any "magic" involved.  Galadriel said, '... this is what your folk would call magic. I believe; though I do not understand clearly what they mean; and they seem also to use the same word of the deceits of the Enemy. '"

Comment: Anduril, as Narsil, was also made in the First Age, though by a Dwarf, which might or might not have made Mithril more likely.  Guthwine (Eomer's sword), made in later in Rohan, was much less likely to have exotic material.